# Приглашение в чат не локализовано

Tags: дефект, локализация, нет-в-transifex, чат, уведомления

События из чата, прокидываемые в глобальный входящий список, например, приглашение в чат, не локализованы:

> [image: invited]

Более того, их нет в transifex. Предвижу замечание о том, что чат пока не подлежит локализации, но хочу заметить, что это сообщение приходит именно на сайт, и его хорошо бы видеть именно на языке сайта.

Как вариант, можно рассмотреть возможность вообще удаления этого сообщения, т.к. по сути оно дублирует заголовок: "приглашение в чат".

Баг-репорт на MSE: [Chat invitation message is not able to localize](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/296140/339911)

Comment: Я за удаление сообщения, оно избыточное.

Comment: Не понял, что оно дублирует.

Comment: @Qwertiy текст серым и черным говорит по сути об одном